# Trying to understand the fibre product in the category of spaces over $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand the fibre product in the category of spaces over $X$.

So let $p: Y \to X, q: Z \to X$ be two spaces over $X$ en let $Y \times_X Z$ be the subspace of $Y \times Z$ such, that $p(y)=q(z)$ for alle $(y,z) \in Y \times Z$. It is equiped with natural projections $q_Y: Y \times_X Z \to Y, p_Z: Y \times_X Z \to Z$ making the appropiate diagram commute [i.e.: $\forall (y,z) \in Y \times_X Z: p \circ q_Y ((y,z)) = q \circ p_Z ((y,z))$].

The statement in my book says, this construction satisfies a universal property: *"it represents the set-valued functor in the category of spaces over $X$ that maps a space $S\to X$ to the set of pairs of morphisms $(\phi: S \to Y, \psi: S\to Z)$ over $X$ satisfying $p \circ \phi = q \circ \psi$".*

I'm stuck at constructing this functor, so I cannot follow this claim. This is what I have so far.

Let $\textbf{Space}_X$ be the category of spaces of $X$, and let, for every $S \in \textbf{Space}_X$, $\alpha_S$ bet the set $\{(\varphi, \psi)| \varphi \in \text{Hom}_X(S,Y), \psi \in \text{Hom}_X(S,Z); p \circ \varphi = q \circ \psi \}$. So we need a functor

\begin{align*}
F: \textbf{Space}_X &\to \textbf{Sets}\\
[\pi_S: S \to X] &\mapsto \alpha_S\\
\text{Hom}_X(S,T) &\to \text{Hom}(\alpha_S,\alpha_T)
\end{align*}

My question is, where would you sent a $f \in \text{Hom}_X(S,T)$ to? If it was a contravariant functor, perhaps you could send $f$ to $F(f): \alpha_T \to \alpha_S$ which sends a $(\varphi_T,\psi_T) \in \alpha_T$ to $(\varphi_T \circ f, \psi_T\circ f) \in \alpha_S$. Is this the way to go?

If we have found such a functor, am I correct in understanding the claim that $F \cong \text{Hom}(Y \times_X Z,-)$. If I want to give such a isomorphism of functors, I need to give an isomorphism $\Phi_{Y \times_X Z}: \alpha_{Y \times_X Z} \to \text{End}(Y \times_X Z), \Phi_S: \alpha_S \to \text{Hom}(Y \times_X Z,S)$ such that the appropiate diagram commutes. Any hint in this would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong functor. You should be looking at morphisms _into_ the fibre product.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the quote I gave, or does he have a different construction?

Answer (score 1):

In any category $\mathbf C$ a *product* of two objects $A,B$ is an object $P$ with two morphisms $p_1: P \to A, p_2: P \to B$  with the universal property that for any object $C$ the map

$$\mathbf C(C,P) \to \mathbf C(C,A) \times \mathbf C(C,B),$$

given by $f \mapsto (p_1 f,p_2 f)$, is a bijection. The fibre product of two spaces over $X$ is the product in the category of spaces over $X$. This just expands Zhen Lin's comment a bit.